# How to create controller to handle the url in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a function of jquery that get the value from the select box, and then I assign the url of the current page to "http://localhost/Products?availability=High&priceSort=Low&tab=2"
and I want to query the products in database by taking the parameter string of my url. Anyone know how can I take these parameter string to query in my controller using linq to sql  and then I can get the result from database according to the value from URL.

I'm doing that with the filter box in the page of my view. I want to use the parameter string in my url to filter the products that I query from database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    // http://localhost/Products/Search?availability=High&priceSort=Low&tab=2
    public ActionResult Search(string availability, string priceSort, int tab)
    {
        // your implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you  explain me clearly? because I'm just the beginner about that. Hope you not mind.

Comment: If you can update your question with more information about what you have so far, that would be helpful.  I'm not quite sure what you're looking for at this point.

Comment: Query string parameters are automatically passed into corresponding method parameters of action methods. So if you have a query string paraeter of "availability" and an action method parameter named the same, that parameter will get its value from the query string.

Comment: Thanks for putting it so succinctly Phil. Hope the new job is treating you well! :)